# Is this a new way to define private instance variables in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I've recently updated to Xcode 4.3.2 and found that I can now declare private instance variables inside `@implementation` block like so:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *testProp;
@end

@implementation TestClass {
    NSString *_testPropStore;
}

- (NSString *)testProp { return _testPropStore; }
- (void)setTestProp:(NSString *)testProp { _testPropStore = [testProp copy]; }

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _testPropStore = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Notice the `NSString *_testPropStore` line inside `@implementation` brace block.

I've also tested with the following code:

```
TestClass *c1 = [[TestClass alloc] init];
TestClass *c2 = [[TestClass alloc] init];

c1.testProp = @"Hello";
c2.testProp = @"World";

NSAssert(c1.testProp == c2.testProp, @"It's working!");
```

Which seems to work fine. (That is, the app crashes with the "It's working" message at the NSAssert line.)

**So is this a new feature of Objective-C for declaring private instance variables? Since I discovered this by accident, I would love to know if it is just for declaring private instance variables or will there be any side effects that I'm not aware of?**

I couldn't find any relevant document since most questions of such type with the word `private` just ended up with answers on how to declare them on a private extension category which is different.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's for real, it's the new way,* it's great, and, yes, it's in the docs. [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF126), which is as close as we get to having an actual spec for the language, has the following to say:

> The definition of a class is structured very much like its declaration. It begins with an `@implementation` directive and ends with the `@end` directive. In addition, the class may declare instance variables in braces after the `@implementation` directive:

```
@implementation ClassName
{
    // Instance variable declarations.
}
// Method definitions.
@end
```

There's also a historical note a little ways back from that link, addressing the fact that we used to have to declare ivars in the interface block:

> Historically, the interface required declarations of a class’s instance variables, the data structures that are part of each instance of the class. ... Instance variables represent an implementation detail, and should typically not be accessed outside of the class itself. Moreover, you can declare them in the implementation block or synthesize them using declared properties. Typically you should not, therefore, declare instance variables in the public interface and so you should omit the braces.

For the question of privacy, yes, these variables are truly private -- they act like ivars declared in the interface with the `@private` directive. This means that subclasses can't access them, by default. Their visibility can be changed, however, using either `@protected` or (if necessary for some bizarre reason) `@public`:

```
@interface Stuper : NSObject 
@end

@implementation Stuper
{
    @protected
    NSString * sangfroid;
}
@end

@interface Stub : Stuper
- (void)setSangfroid: (NSString *)newSangfroid;
@end

@implementation Stub

- (void)setSangfroid: (NSString *)newSangfroid {
    sangfroid = [newSangfroid copy];
}
```

---

*You have to use clang > 3.0, I believe, so that's just a few months ago as of this posting. GCC won't do it.

Comment: I'm more curious how this is done under the hood. How does the Objective-C runtime know how much memory to allocate for the class if the header has an incomplete definition?

Comment: That would be a great question to post. It almost certainly has something to do with ["non-fragile ivars"](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html).

Comment: FYI, the link in your answer appears to be broken for me.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, @AndrewWhite, they got rid of the TOCPL document, which sucks. I've got dozens of answers with links to it and I'm not sure what to replace them with.

Comment: This is the working link now
(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Thanks, @Norbert, but that page doesn't include any information about ivars.

Comment: You are right.. I didn't read it all before posting here. Got so excited I could help the community for once :D

Comment: Don't let this stop you, @Norbert! I'd love to find a good doc link for this.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty new and it's valid as long as any compiler you need supports it.

It's great for minimizing your dependencies -- the includes and forwards may largely be in the  implementation file. For this reason, and if all the compilers you use support it, then it's a better place for your ivars than in the `@interface` block.

A final caveat is that our current (may.2.2012) debuggers do not support this.

Comment: Very good point about the debuggers. There's a small thread about this on the lldb.devel list: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.debugging.lldb.devel/624