# lldb error: use of undeclared identifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, lldb

Anyone know whats going on here:

```
@implementation Test
{
    NSData *_data;
}

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _data = data;
    } 
    return self;  // BREAKPOINT HERE
}
```

From lldb:

```
(lldb) p data
(NSData *) $1 = 0x07f911e0 30308 bytes
(lldb) p _data
error: use of undeclared identifier '_data'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Why can't I view `_data`?

Answer (score -1):

I've only ever seen data fields declared in an `@interface` block; you appear to be defining fields in the `@implementation`.

Try putting this in the header instead, e.g.

```
@interface Test
{
    NSData *_data;
}
. . .
@end
```

Comment: This is a new-ish Clang feature; it's perfectly legal and really nice. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407848/is-this-a-new-way-to-define-private-instance-variables-in-objective-c/10407891#10407891

Comment: Neat.  I guess I can use it for iOS but not older Mac development. :)  In any case I suspect it may still be a factor in why a debugging tool cannot see the field.

Comment: Yes, lldb seems to still be having some rough times with ivars. I posted an answer here (now deleted) addressing that.

Comment: I'm still seeing this error message. Not even involving ivar, it's a local variable.