# lldb error: use of undeclared identifier with local variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, lldb, mapbox

I've seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488361/lldb-error-use-of-undeclared-identifier). However, I'm having trouble not with ivar but with a regular instant varible.

In Mapbox-ios-sdk there is this code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)] autorelease];
singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
singleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

I tried printing singletapRecognizer there and there is some output. But not when I use debugger:

```
(lldb) po singleTapRecognizer
error: use of undeclared identifier 'singleTapRecognizer'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure you are at the right *scope* within `lldb`?

Comment: Yes, I've just verified it just now.