# What are the differences between declaring objects in extension and declaring them in primary implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, extension-methods, categories

I was reading about categories and extension in objective c here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

it says i can declare objects in extensions like this...

CASE 1

```
@interface XYZPerson () {
    id _someCustomInstanceVariable;
}
@end
@implementation XYZPerson {
...
}
...
@end
```

and I have seen pieces of code where objects are declared in implementaion (.m) files, like this...

CASE 2

```
@interface XYZPerson () {
    ...
}
@end
@implementation XYZPerson {
      id _someCustomInstanceVariable;
}
...
@end
```

My question is: What is the difference between "_someCustomInstanceVariable" declared in extension and the one declared in implementation.
Extensions can be used to make objects private, but "id _someCustomInstanceVariable" is private in second case too.

Comment: Refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407848/is-this-a-new-way-to-define-private-instance-variables-in-objective-c

Comment: Thanks Matin R and Amar :)